# Problem with Picard iteration and defining solution interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

So I am supposed to have a closer look at the initial value problem $$y' = y^2 + e^{-x^2}, y(0) = 0$$
The first point to show is whether the DEQ has a solution for $|x| \leq 1/2$.For this I used the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, which gives me the following inequality:
$$x \leq min(A, B/{(B^2 + 1)}) $$ with $|x| \leq A$ and $|y| \leq B$.
So I can just set $A,B$ accordingly to get $|x| \leq 1/2$. This however would imply to me that I can just make $A$ very big and $B$ as close to $0$ as needed to extend the solution interval for $x$ to the whole real numbers. (This seems strange and wrong to me but I can't find the mistake). Lastly I am supposed to give a reason why this DEQ causes problems for the Picard iteration. After looking at a few iterations I can say that the integral blows up heavily but this shouldn't be a sufficient argument against the iteratin, so if someone has an idea where the problem really is: I would really appreciate a hint...

Thanks in advance

Comment: with constant $C > 0,$   what happens with  related problem $y' = y^2$  and $y(0) = C \; ? \; \; $

Comment: We would get $|y-C| \leq B$ instead. The Lipschitz continuity for $f$ in the secon variable would still hold. However the min(A, B/(sup |f(x,y)|)) would change. Is this what you are eluding to or am I missing something else?

Comment: Mostly that it blows up in finite time.   I expect this for your problem as well. One way to find out for sure is to change variables; for instance, try $y = \tan u(x) $   where $u(0) = 0.$   If inequalities show that there is an $x_0$  with $u(x_0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ that means $y$   blows up to infinity at that $x_0$

Comment: Sorry seemingly I am too stupid to get the point. l mean the rectangle on which we operate bounds the x and y and thus the functions depending on them. (Otherwise we wouldn't have the lipschitz continuity in the second variable). Because we have this we get $|f(x,y) - f(x,z)| \leq (|y| + |z|) * |y-z|$ which holds for any (x,y) and (x,z) in our rectangle, right? So I don't see the problem yet :/

Comment: I see you bound $x < 1/2,$    maybe you are right that no trouble occurs

Answer (score 1):

The second term in the minimum, $\frac{B}{1+B^2}$, goes to zero as $B$ goes to infinity, the denominator grows faster than the numerator. It takes indeed its largest value $\frac12$ at $B=1$.

You can get a slightly larger interval of existence by computing an upper bound, as $e^{-x^2}<1$ the solution has as upper bound the solution of $u'=u^2+1$, giving $x\le \frac\pi2$.